# Executing program on remote with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm having trouble executing a program on a remote server. This is my command

```
$appCommand = "`"c:\SIDApps\{0}\{1}.exe`"" -f $destinationDirectory, $processToKill

        Invoke-Command  -ComputerName $remoteComputer  -Credential $credentials -ScriptBlock  { $args[0] } -ArgumentList $appCommand
```

That prints out `"c:\SIDApps\FFMBC_Drone\GCUKTransCodeServiceFFMBCApp.exe"` (Including the quotes) in the output window, but does not actually execute the program

Answer (score 0):

If you only output `$args[0]` in the `ScriptBlock` it will only display the path not run the command.

Have you tried this ?

```
$appCommand = "c:\SIDApps\{0}\{1}.exe" -f $destinationDirectory, $processToKill

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteComputer -Credential $credentials -ScriptBlock { Start-Process $args[0] } -ArgumentList $appCommand
```